# service fabric package command fails when called from tfs

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-on-premises

While building service fabric the package command runs file in local machine, but fails when this is added as a build steps in TFS/VSTS.
We are using onPrem build agent.

dotnet msbuild DependentServices.sfproj /t:Package

It throws error:

> The process cannot access the file 'D:\TFS
>   BuildAgent\BuildAgent4_work\4\s\CommonLibraries\Model.dll' because it
>   is being used by another process.

Comment: Is `\CommonLibraries\Model.dll` being generated during your build?

Comment: yes it is generated. but the build is a different step before package.

Comment: you command is looking somewhat weird? is it a single command or two commands?

Comment: When you say the build and package are in different "step" you're saying they are different tasks in the same job, correct? If they are in different jobs, then you **may** need to make sure they are running in sequence and not in parallel. [Build jobs run in parallel by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/multiple-phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=designer#dependencies).

Comment: Yes they are different steps in the same job. But I have 3 projects/application to package and they are using same common dlls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try suggestions from this article [Troubleshoot Build and Release: File- and folder-in-use errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting?view=azure-devops#file--and-folder-in-use-errors)? Sections: **Detect files and folders in use** and **Anti-virus exclusion**

Comment: setting noreuse to false and limiting cpu to 1 fixed it.